# Piecewise PDE Over 3 Regions with Continuity Boundary Conditions

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, symbolic, piecewise

I am using Wolfram Language for the first time for my research and could really use some help! I am trying to find the **analytical** solution of a PDE which has piecewise constants and a piecewise input.

The PDE is to model the lithium-ion concentration in an electrolyte solution of a battery (in 1-dimension, x), and it has three regions, the Cathode, Separator, and Anode. This plot is an example to show these regions and the concentration gradient that the PDE is predicting:

[image]

*(Ignore that the plot and axis above the plot don't line up perfectly, it's what I had available)*

So with that background, this is the PDE:

[image]

Which in code I have as:

```
pde={-(yi  J[s]/(A Li ai)) + s ce[x,s] - De * D[ce[x,s],{x,2}] == 0}
```

With the general analytical solution found by:

```
pdesoln=DSolve[pde,ce,{x,s}]
```

But Li and ai have different constant values in the Anode vs. the Cathode region. Also important, I(s)=0 in the separator region. So I tried to tackle this as 3 separate PDEs rather than a single piecewise PDE, with the intention of stitching the PDEs together at the end based on their boundary conditions. (So 1 PDE for the anode region, 1 for the separtor, and 1 for the cathode). The boundary conditions of the PDEs are:

[image]

Essentially there's 1 Neumann and 1 Dirichlet B.C. at each interior boundary, and 1 Neumann B.C. at each end of the battery cell. The problem I'm really running into is that the interior B.C.'s are all based off the solutions of the other PDEs, and I don't know how to stitch them together.

I think I've imposed the exterior Neumann B.C.'s correctly...

Anode:

```
pdeanode={-(yn  J/(A Ln an)) + s ceanode[x,s] - De * D[ceanode[x,s],{x,2}] == 0}
icanode = {Derivative[1,0][ceanode][0,s] ==0};
pdeanodesoln=DSolve[{pdeanode,icanode},ceanode,{x,s}]
pdeanode/.pdeanodesoln[[1]] //Simplify
```

Cathode:

```
pdecathode={-(yp  J/(A Lp ap)) + s cecathode[x,s] - De * D[cecathode[x,s],{x,2}] == 0}
iccathode = {Derivative[1,0][cecathode][Lc,s] ==0};
pdecathodesoln=DSolve[{pdecathode,iccathode},cecathode,{x,s}]
pdecathode/.pdecathodesoln[[1]] //Simplify
```

*Note: J used in place of I(s) becuase I is interpreted as an imaginary number*

And I defined the Separator region PDE as this, given I(s)=0 in the separator:

```
pdesep={s cesep[x,s] - De * D[cesep[x,s],{x,2}] == 0}
pdesepsoln=DSolve[pdesep,cesep,{x,s}]
pdesep/.pdesepsoln[[1]] //Simplify
```

But I am not able to impose any boundary conditions to this atm. Or more accurately, I don't know how to stitch these 3 PDEs together. Can somebody help me out? It'd be greatly appreciated!